# Найти в файле значение и изменить его на другое

Tags: php

Вот скрипт парсинга

```
<?php

class Currency
{
    /*      Config          */
    //  адрес для обновлений
    var $updURL = 'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp';
    //  путь для сохранения файлов modules/currency/currency/
    var $path = 'currency/';
    //  префикс файлов
    var $fPrefix = 'curs_';
    //  сохранять историю (не удалять старые файлы)?
    var $keepHistory = false;
    //  какие валюты участвуют в статистике?
    var $currArray = array('840', '978', '980');
    //  сравнить курсы со вчерашними?
    var $changes = true;

    function __construct()
    {
        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        $mydate = explode('-', $today);
        //  нужно ли обновление?
        if (!file_exists($this->path . $this->fPrefix . $today . '.php')) {
            //  обновляем файл
            $currentCurrency = array();
            $x = 0;
            $upd = simplexml_load_file($this->updURL);
            foreach ($upd as $node) {

            if (in_array($node->NumCode[0], $this->currArray)) {
                    $currentCurrency[$x]['Value'] = $node->Value[0];
                    $currentCurrency[$x]['CharCode'] = $node->CharCode[0];
                    $x++;
                }

            }
            //запись
            $this->save2file($currentCurrency, $today);
            if (!$this->keepHistory) {
                $ago = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mydate[1], $mydate[2] - 2, $mydate[0]));

                if (file_exists($this->path . $this->fPrefix . $ago . '.php')) {
                    unlink($this->path . $this->fPrefix . $ago . '.php');
                }
            }
        }
        //показываем информацию из файла
        require_once ($this->path . $this->fPrefix . $today . '.php');
        $this->view($currency);
    }

    function save2file($arr, $today)
    {
        //  запишем новую инфу в файл
        $h = fopen($this->path . $this->fPrefix . $today . '.php', "w");

        fwrite($h, '<?php $currency = Array(); ');
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
        {
            fwrite($h, '$currency[\'' . $v['CharCode'] . '\'] = \'' . $v['Value']=str_replace(',','.',$v['Value']) . '\'; '); // fwrite($h, '$currency[\'' . $v['CharCode'] . '\'] = \'' . $v['Value'] . '\'; ');
        }

   //     fwrite($h, '$currency[\'UAH\'] = \'' . $v['Value']/10 . '\'; ');

        fwrite($h, ' ?>');
        fclose($h);   
    }

    function view($arr)
    {
        // сравнение курсов
        if ($this->changes) {
             $today = date("Y-m-d");
             $date = date("d.m.Y");
            $mydate = explode('-', $today);
            $yesterday = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mydate[1], $mydate[2] - 1, $mydate[0]));

            if (file_exists($this->path . $this->fPrefix . $yesterday . '.php')) {

                require_once ($this->path . $this->fPrefix . $yesterday . '.php');

                foreach ($currency as $key => $value) {
                    if ($arr[$key] > $currency[$key]) {
                        $arr['x'][$key]['change'] = 'currency/up.gif';
                        $arr['x'][$key]['Value'] = $arr[$key];
                    } elseif ($arr[$key] < $currency[$key]) {
                        $arr['x'][$key]['change'] = 'currency/down.gif';
                        $arr['x'][$key]['Value'] = $arr[$key];
                    } elseif ($arr[$key] == $currency[$key]) {
                        $arr['x'][$key]['change'] = 'currency/null.gif';
                        $arr['x'][$key]['Value'] = $arr[$key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!is_array($arr['x'])) {

            echo '<table width=100%><center><font size=2 color=#009900><small>на ' . $date . '</small></font></center>';
            foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
                echo '<tr><td><img src="currency/' . $k . '.png"></td><td>' . $v . '</td></tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo '<table width=100%><center><font size=2 color=#009900><small>на ' . $date . '</small></font></center>';
            foreach ($arr['x'] as $k => $v) {
                echo '<tr><td><img src="currency/' . $k . '.png"></td><td>' . $v['Value'] . '</td><td><img src="' . $v['change'] . '"></td></tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        }
    }
}
$curr = new Currency();
?>
```

Скрипт создает файлы  файл curs_ДАта.php с новыми курсами а старый удаляет с таким содержимым:

```
<?php $currency = Array(); $currency['USD'] = '46.3379'; $currency['EUR'] = '57.8575'; $currency['UAH'] = '29.2353'; ?>
```

Изначально курс гривны идет за десять единиц '29.2353'. А нужно чтоб было за одну иресть так 2.9235. Подскажите, как сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$currency['UAH'] = (string)number_format( 0,1 * (float)$currency['UAH'], 4 );
```

Как ты отслеживаешь изменения курсов валют из вопроса, неясно.